# Magento: Use setup-model out of magento

Tags: magento

It is possible to use the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup` out of Magento?

```
require_once "app/Mage.php";
Mage::app();

//Use the setup model
```

I want to use the attribute functionality (addAttribute(), etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just like you would do so in Magento:

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::init();

$setup = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup', 'core_setup');
$setup->addAttribute(...);
```

Comment: This does not work unfortunately...

Fatal error: Call to a member function select() on a non-object in app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php on line 734

Comment: The solution is: $setup = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup', 'core_setup');

Comment: user215421: you are life saver.