# getting setup model

Tags: magento

I want create new table out of magento, in interface, without inheriting setup class. I tried to get resource model of setup. This didn't work:

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::init();

$setup = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup');
```

I was also thinking about `Mage::getResourceModel('core/resource_setup')` but i have an error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function startSetup() on a non-object in C:\xampp\
htdocs\LPP_MAGENTO_EE_CUSTOM\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php on
 line 944`

Do you have any idea?
(I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759341/magento-use-setup-model-out-of-magento/11396693#11396693) but it doesn't work for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it with `$setup = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_setup', 'core_setup')` example for create new attribute for Category within my code:

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::init();
$setup = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_setup', 'core_setup');

$setup->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'xxx', array(
...
));
```

Comment: Your solution is ok, but I need something else. I should be more specific. I need to do few selects and inserts to database. I thougth it will work and print the result:
`$view_declaration = '';
$model->startSetup();
$view_declaration = $model->run("
    SELECT VIEW_DEFINITION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS;
    ");
$model->endSetup();
echo $view_declaration;` but it isn't :(

Comment: Method startSetup is only in Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup, nowhere else. If you need just do selects or inserts may be just use method like http://www.richardcastera.com/blog/magento-how-to-run-a-sql-query-against-the-database.